# Flash Builder case insensitive sort with AdvancedDatagrid header click

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, case-sensitive, advanceddatagrid

After reading all I could find on the subject I implemented the following sortCompareFunction...

```
private function value_sortCompareFunc(itemA:Object, itemB:Object):int {
    return ObjectUtil.stringCompare(itemA.value, itemB.value, true);
}
```

When the datagrid is loaded the datasource has been sorted (case insensitive) by the backend database as follows.

```
Ababa, Meaghan
abadilla, Athena
Adams, AJ Jordan
....
....
Lin, Jia
etc...
```

At this point the sort is good and case insensitive.

However, when the user clicks the header for this column I get.

```
Lin, Jia
Ababa, Meaghan
abadilla, Athena
Adams, AJ Jordan
etc...
```

Except for the first name, the rest appears to be sorted corectly. Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug?

Thanks,

John

Datgrid code (I have not put the sortCompareFunction setting in the other alpha columns yet)....

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="studentsAdvDG" x="11" y="100" width="754" height="308"change="{isOneStudentSelected()}"
    dataProvider="{studentsAllforDG}" designViewDataType="tree"
    doubleClick="{studentsDG_doubleClickHandler(event)}"
    doubleClickEnabled="true
    horizontalGridLineColor="#CDCBCB" horizontalGridLines="true"
    selectionColor="#A5C5DA" selectionMode="multipleRows"
    styleFunction="studentsAdvDGStyleFunc" textAlign="left"
    useRollOver="false" variableRowHeight="true">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn width="210" dataField="student"headerText="Student" textAlign="left"
                    sortCompareFunction="value_sortCompareFunc"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn width="40" dataField="projectID"headerText="ID"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn visible="{registrarType != 'SchoolCoordinator'}" width="169" dataField="studentSchool" headerText="School"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn visible="{registrarType == 'SchoolCoordinator' || showTeacherButton.label == 'Show Contact'}" width="169" dataField="teacher" headerText="Teacher"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn visible="{showTeacherButton.label == 'Show Teacher'}" width="185" dataField="studentContact" headerText="Contact"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn width="65" dataField="studentPackageStatus" headerText="Status"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="studentUploadDate" headerText="Upload"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn visible="false" dataField="studentEmail" headerText="studentEmail"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn visible="false" dataField="studentID" headerText="studentID"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn visible="false" dataField="studentPackageDirty" headerText="studentPackageDirty"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn visible="false" dataField="studentPW" headerText="studentPW"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn visible="false" dataField="studentNeedsvalidation" headerText="studentNeedsvalidation"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the in the specified column as sortable = false. Then there will be no effect if you will click the header. See the answer below

```
   <mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="myADG"  width="100%" height="100%" dataProvider="{theModel.quiz_member_list}"
                     >
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="S.No" dataField="sNo" width="55" sortable="false" />
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Name" dataField="username" sortable="false" />
    </mx:columns>
   </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

Comment: But I do want the dg to be sorted when a header is clicked. I just want it to be case insensitive. Am I missing sometning in your answer? The problem is that the first row is out of order.